# SSH Added, but still fatal Could not read from remote repository

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh

When I do the following:

```
$ git pull origin master
```

it returns:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

As directed by GitHub instructions I have verified the following:

1) Created a key using the following command:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myemail@gmail.com"` and named it GitHub
which returned:

```
Your identification has been saved in GitHub.
Your public key has been saved in GitHub.pub.
```

2) Added to my SSH Agent in both the .ssh directory and the local repo location:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

and

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/GitHub
```

which returned:

```
Identity added: /Users/myUserName/.ssh/GitHub (/Users/myUserName/.ssh/GitHub)
```

3) Copied the key using `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/GitHub.pub`
and pasted the key in the appropriate settings area in GitHub settings page.

4) From my local repo location I do a `ssh -T git@github.com` and it returns:

```
Hi ConfusedDeer! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

5) I also do a  `ssh-add -l` to verify it has been added to my ssh agent and it returns: `4096 SHA256:PcgDpZHUEepM/cQvVn525I5fgwCgVj98wEloWiosQ4s /Users/myUserName/.ssh/GitHub (RSA)`

6) I did a `git remote -v` to verify the origin location is correct and it returns:

```
origin  ssh://github.com/ConfusedDeer/myiOSapp.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://github.com/ConfusedDeer/myiOSapp.git (push)
```

and I compare them to the my GitHub account and it seems fine: `git@github.com:ConfusedDeer/myiOSapp.git`

7) I noticed the newly added GitHub key on the settings interface was black, but after I did the `ssh -T git@github.com` it is now green and states: `Added on Mar 19, 2017 Last used within the last day`

Did I miss a step? Any other troubleshooting steps I could try? Suggestions?

Comment: Is user added to the project at github? Simple but worth checking.

Comment: @zatta can you be a bit more specific please? Do you mean I need to add myself as a "collaborator"? When I tried that it stated: "Repository owner cannot be a collaborator"

Comment: What is the question? What are you trying to achieve? What does not work?

Comment: @Jakuje as I stated in the question: When I do the following:

$ git pull origin master
It returns:it returns:

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: as it is written, it looks like it did it before setting all of that. Post the verbose log from `ssh -vvvT git@github.com`. Also I would consider updating the URL to `ssh://git@github.com/ConfusedDeer/myiOSapp.git`

Comment: Could you also check if ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub is there? Ssh might using that public key instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to switch my remote urls from HTTPS to SSH: I found [instructions on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh).

I needed to change

**FROM:**

```
origin  ssh://github.com/ConfusedDeer/myiOSapp.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://github.com/ConfusedDeer/myiOSapp.git (push)
```

**TO:**

```
origin  git@github.com:ConfusedDeer/myiOSapp.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:ConfusedDeer/myiOSapp.git (push)
```

by doing the following command:

`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:ConfusedDeer/myiOSapp.git`

Comment: ssh://git@github.. should also work, glad you found it!

Answer (score 0):

Your github account does not show any repositories.

1. Does the repository actually *exist*? (Just open it in the browser. E.g. for `ssh://github.com/ConfusedDeer/myiOSapp.git` open `http://github.com/ConfusedDeer/myiOSapp`)
2. Try a fresh clone: `git clone ssh://github.com/ConfusedDeer/myiOSapp.git` and see if that works

Comment: They are all private.

Comment: Ok, that explains why I cannot see them. Have you tried my comments though?

Comment: A fresh clone might have worked, since technically that should have written out the correct remote URLs. I was able to figure out the solution, without having to do that, which was easier because I had numerous changes to commit. thanks.